# Quartz scheduler and OSGI

Tags: osgi, quartz-scheduler

I have an OSGI scheduler bundle that has the Quartz Scheduler Jar in it.
This bundle exposes just an application interface to other bundles and, when a new job is registered, it is wrapped into a temporaryJob (that implements StatefulJob) and scheduled using the scheduler.

In this way I don't have to expose Quartz Scheduler jar (that it is not so much osgi compliant).
The problem with this approach is that, since StatefulJob avoids to execute job in parallel and I have only one actual job (the temporaryJob), all my real jobs run one at a time.

Unfortunately it seems that the marker interface is the only way to say that the job is a stateful one.
The only solution I could find is to make the daemon exposing the StatefulJobInterface (removing the fake job), but doing so, I am having a lot of classpath problems.
Is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: Are you keeping from exposing Quartz directly because of complexities (class loader, etc) or for looser coupling to quartz? Apache Sling has a scheduler bundle[1] that uses quartz but hides that through their interface.
1 http://sling.apache.org/site/eventing-and-jobs.html

Comment: Another alternative is to use camel-quartz, http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html - which plays nicely in an OSGi environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a real Quartz OSGi bundle, such as the one available here:

http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/detail?name=com.springsource.org.quartz

The latest Quartz version available there is 1.6.2. If you need a newer version, building your own bundle is pretty easy with [bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd) or [bundlor](http://www.springsource.org/bundlor).

Then you can expose StatefulJob as a service anywhere in your OSGi environment, and have your scheduler bundle register and deregister those jobs with Quartz. Even better, have the scheduler bundle listen for any services that are wrappers around your trigger and job information, such as the Spring [CronTriggerBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerBean.html) or [SimpleTriggerBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerBean.html). This way,

1) your internal API / OSGi services are not Quartz specific -- only the scheduling bundle has a dependency on the Quartz bundle, and

2) your application bundles can determine the job's schedule instead of the scheduling bundle trying to figure that out.

Update: Newer Quartz OSGi bundles are available from the ServiceMix project: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find newer Quartz OSGI bundles (up to version 2.2.0 at the time of writing):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz

Comment: This doesn't work because it misses commonj.work when resolving. Now, try to get that being resolved as well :-)

Comment: @PauloPires did you manage to figure out the commonj problem?

Comment: check karaf's `camel-quartz` [feature](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/2.12.3/apache-camel-2.12.3-features.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You can install these bundles

```
bundle:install wrap:mvn:c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2
bundle:install mvn:org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.2
bundle:install wrap:mvn:org.quartz-scheduler/quartz-jobs/2.2.2
```

You will need these dependency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2_1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```