# Quartz Scheduler and usage dependencies on Karaf not starting an OSGi bundle

Tags: java, maven, quartz-scheduler, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am trying to use Quartz Scheduler on Apache Karaf :

I used Scheduler example on [Apache Karaf Github page](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/scheduler/pom.xml).

On my IDE, I executed an example and it works fine but I can not install and start the bundle under in Karaf.

An here's the POM Import and Export of packages :

```
    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
    <Export-Package>
         com.schedule*;version=${project.version}
    </Export-Package>                        
    <Import-Package>
         !com.mchange.*,
         !oracle.*,
         !org.quartz.management,
         !weblogic.*,
         !javax.transaction,
         *
    </Import-Package>
    <Private-Package>
         org.apache.karaf.scheduler.core,
         org.apache.karaf.scheduler.command.*,
         org.quartz,
         org.quartz.core.*,
         org.quartz.listeners.*,
         org.quartz.impl.*,
         org.quartz.spi.*,
         org.quartz.simpl.*,
         org.quartz.utils.*,
     </Private-Package>
```

The problem is Karaf Import packages and exclusions.
Here's Karaf logs :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/ee/jta/JTAAnnotationAwareJobRunShellFactory
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1204)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1519)
    at com.soprahr.hub.bc.schedule.core.SimpleSchedule.init(SimpleSchedule.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:980)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:736)
    ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.ee.jta.JTAAnnotationAwareJobRunShellFactory not found by com.schedule. [311]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help, Wrapping the Quartz jar can help to resolve this problem and use the dependency as a jar. That's why we need these dependencies :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3_1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And to install it in Karaf, we can use these commands with wrap prefix :

```
 bundle:install wrap:mvn:c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2
 bundle:install mvn:org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.2
 bundle:install wrap:mvn:org.quartz-scheduler/quartz-jobs/2.2.2
```

I got my answer on this page : [Quartz scheduler and OSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006548/quartz-scheduler-and-osgi)

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question but if it doesn't have to explicitly be the Quartz scheduler you could use the scheduler from the Apache Sling project. It works just fine in Karaf. Just install the bundle in any way you want and you are ready to go.

A little howto can be found [here](http://wiki.rpgnextgen.com/doku.php?id=osgi_task_scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

Actually Karaf does have a scheduler out-of-the-box. Therefore why not use that one. It actually is very similar to the one provided by SLING. 
To use it the following commands are available:

install via

```
feature:install scheduler
```

list all scheduled jobs:

```
scheduler:list
```

schedule a new job:

```
scheduler:schedule
```

for details about the parameters take a look at

```
scheduler:schedule --help
```

for unscheduling a job:

```
scheduler:unschedule <name>
```